# React, JWT/Cookie and Routes

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt, navigation, client

I'm currently working on a web app where I've implemented JWT authentication. The server creates the JWT token and sends it to the client in an HttpOnly cookie. I'm using React for the frontend and facing challenges in managing authentication state during navigation.

I've attempted to use `useContext` in React and fetch the token via a `useEffect` in the `App` component that wraps my routes. However, I'm encountering issues, especially when refreshing the page. It seems that the asynchronous nature of `useEffect` is causing bugs. Initially, no token is fetched (returns null), and then, if a token is fetched, it persists even after the initial null value.

I'm looking for guidance on a more robust solution to handle JWT authentication in React, specifically with HttpOnly cookies. How can I ensure that the token is properly checked during navigation, avoiding the issues I'm currently facing?

Any help or insights into best practices for managing JWT authentication in React would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to use localstorage than cookie.
It looks like cookie saved in every page and does not saved in browser.